# Where are the easter eggs in The Talos Principle?

Tags: the-talos-principle

Where are the easter eggs in The Talos Principle and how do you obtain them?

These are the easter eggs I have found:

1. > At the messenger place at hall B there is a secret path underwater, which leads to The Swapper statue.
2. > At some world in B there is a boarded up "door", which you can break with a metal [tool?]
3. > At B4 right near teleport you can open stone" " door and see "Entry denied" message. It is "usable", but I don't know how to activate it.
4. > At some world in C, near "7 doors" puzzle you can find a Minecraft sword.
5. > At some world at B (B2? the one with 4 statues and the star near them) you can find a hole with a bed.

and I think there should be more.

Comment: There's a ton more, see [this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=355489493)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, Thanks. This could be a complete answer, which I can accept. Just put the link and cite the content plz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information (slightly modified and reformatted) from http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=355489493&insideModal=1

> 1. World A Hub
>
>    Developer Island: In the Hub, in front of the level 7 teleporter go through the wall on the other side of the hub where a teleporter
>      would be if there were another level between the 6 and the one blocked
>      by wood.
> 2. World A-2
>
>    a) Message in a bottle N°1: Right of the "Hall of Windows" puzzle entrance, between two rocks near the peninsula with two trees.
>
>    b) Message in a bottle N°2: Left of the extra Computer, between some rocks.
> 3. World A-4
>
>    a) Floppy Disk: On the left area near the teleporter you can climb a slope to walk on the wall. You need to follow the path, it will be
>      on top of the white column and the end. When you finally get it, don't
>      forget to check it's content at the nearest computer.
>
>    b) Talkie Walkie: From the teleporter, go straight ahead to the opposite side of the map then jump on the path below. From here go
>      right and jump on the platform across the gap. It will be a bit
>      further ahead after this.
>
>    c) Literal Easter Egg in a nest: Get on the far right side of the area, behind the "Push if Further" puzzle. There is a path going down
>      with a U-turn near a tree. The Egg is hidden on the right side of this
>      turn
> 4. World A-7
>
>    a) SOS Signal: At the far right of the shore, it's written in the sand.
>
>    b) Terminal with Blue Screen of Death: At the far left of the shore, look at the screen of the terminal.
> 5. World A-Star
>
>    Mirror: Right of the entrance of the "Jammed from Within" puzzle. The path is hidden behind some trees.
> 6. World A-Messenger
>
>    Monkey in a cage: In an area behind the waterfall on the right of the teleporter. You can access it by jumping from the right side of
>      the cliff.
> 7. World B-1
>
>    Soldier Helmet: In puzzle "Window through a Door" in the last area where you get the tetromino. You can see it (in 3rd person mode)
>      across one of the wall to the desert. In "Road of Death" take the cube
>      to the other side. Then place it near third window and jump in it.
>      From here go carefully around the map back to where the helmet is.
> 8. World B-2
>
>    a) Bedroom: It's just outside "The Tomb" puzzle. Go right from up
>      the slope leading to the star area. From here you have to jump on the
>      left side of the tomb entrance. Here it will be inside a hole in the
>      ground.
>
>    b) Telescope + Spaaace: On the left side of the moon you can see a
>      connector (Bind the zoom, it help).  Power from the "Moonshot" puzzle
>      using the connector and the red laser. For the telescope, get Inside
>      "Man on the Moon" puzzle. First you need to get the key in the far
>      right area of the puzzle, it's easy to find. The telescope is just
>      above the key. To get there, use the left fan to jump on the platform
>      on the left. To manage this you must hold left and bounce on the
>      column during the jump. Look into the telescope.
> 9. World B-3
>
>    a) Funky Hallway: Just right before the entrance of the "Blown Away" puzzle, go to the shadow on the right. In the corner you'll find
>      a slope leading to this Easter egg.
>
>    b) Pacman: From the entrance, go to 8 o'clock into the corner of the map. If will be just below the palm tree.
> 10. World B-4
>
>     a) Papers Please: Right behind the teleporter you can use the wall and it will open. But it will show you and "entry denied" message. In
>       the "Wrap Around the Corner" puzzle (first one on the left), you will
>       find an "approved" stamp on the Hint Altar. Now go back to the message
>       and stamp it away.
>
>     b) Dynamite: Again in the "Wrap Around the Corner" puzzle, get into the far right area. Then jump from the stairs to the wall. You'll
>       find the dynamite just where you land.  You can then go use it on the
>       Sphinx (left side).
> 11. World B-5
>
>     a) Telescope + Liberty Statue: Behind the "Alley of the Pressure Plates" you will find it in the middle of the sunken structure. To be
>       able to use the telescope you first need to get the key in the water
>       right below it.
>
>     b) Hidden Cave: In the "Behind the Iron Curtain puzzle", get to the fan with 2 boxes and bring those up on the platform. Now put one
>       on the air flow, use the other one to jump on it then take it with you
>       before jumping on the wall. Now jump into the small area below. Here
>       start by sending the box outside using the fan, then take the other
>       fan with you before getting outside. From here take the box and the
>       fan to the other side of the nearest sunken contraption. Use the box
>       to get on the wall and put the fan into the mechanism. Jump on this
>       fan ! You will land right next to the teleporter.
> 12. World B-6
>
>     Sam's Room: You need to climb to the top of the teleporter room. Start from the only stone you can jump on, next jump on the statue and
>       then on the wall. From here jump on the edge sticking out of the
>       exterior wall and follow it to the left until the end. Then jump from
>       column to column until you get to the top.
> 13. World B-7
>
>     a) Coconut tree: From the teleporter, if you look in direction of the pyramid, on the left you will see a leaning obelisk. It's right
>       there, look up.
>
>     b) CRObar + Cube Room: Go left of the "Whole Lotta Jamming" puzzle and follow the wall until you see some ruins. Here you will find
>       Freeman's favourite weapon.From here continue in the direction of the
>       ruins with two obelisks. On the way stop at the half sunken statue. On
>       the ground there is some wooden planks to break. Get inside. Inside
>       the room you can break one of the boxes for a little surprise.
>
>     c) Skeletons: Behind the "Bouncing Side by Side" puzzle on a tiny dune.
> 14. World B-Messenger
>
>     Head Statue "The Swapper" reference: From the entrance, get to the river and follow it in the wrong direction, you'll reach an underwater
>       passageway. You can use the two rocks in front of it.
> 15. World C-1
>
>     a) Glitchy Room with Elohim: Looking at the entrance of the puzzle "The Conservatory", follow the right wall of this puzzle. You will
>       soon hear and see a glitchy square on the ground. Just walk on it.
>       (Having discovered this one myself, I find that if walking on it
>       doesn't trigger it, try jumping on it)
>
>     b) Gnaar Statue: On this map you can find 10 parts of a Gnaar statue hidden a bit everywhere outside the puzzles areas. There is a
>       pedestal on which you can rebuild it for a little surprise.
> 16. World C-2
>
>     a) Fork Parker & Money: From the teleporter, go straight ahead into the red door of the chapel looking building. It's not solid.
>
>     b) Telescope & King Gnaar: Inside the "Rapunzel" puzzle, if you go up the ladder and turn around, you can get a key on the left gargoyle.
>       From here you need to bring up a platform and a Hexahedron. Then
>       record yourself first holding the platform next to the box (so you can
>       jump on it) then jump on the cube to get high enough to reach the
>       telescope. The Gnaar is at the top of one of the mountain.
> 17. World C-3
>
>     a) Gandalf Gnaar: In the "Weathertop" puzzle, head directly to the cliff edge opposite of the entrance and look down.
>
>     b) Serious Sam in Carbonite: Go through the purple field just to the right of the previous easter egg. Here jump down from the cliff
>       edge to small ledge with a tree. Then follow the ledge.
>
>     c) Snowman: In the "Jammer Quarantine" puzzle, it's behind the quarantined jammer on the promontory. I reached it using the jetpack
>       but maybe it's also possible using an Hexahedron. Don't forget to fix
>       up his fallen button for a surprise.
>
>     d) Jetpack: To be able to get this you need to finish every puzzle in this level and get the star. If you don't the path will be closed.
>       In the puzzle "Big Stairs, Little Stairs", go straight ahead of the
>       entrance and to the cliff edge on the right of the blue laser emitter.
>       Here if you jump down carefully you will reach a cave.
>
>     e) Frozen Gnaar Cave: To get in there you need to fly below the entrance of the "Big Stairs, Little Stairs" puzzle using the
>       jetpack.The puzzle to get inside won't be hard to solve if you got
>       that far. You need: 3 Jammers, 2 Hexahedrons, 1 Fan, 1 Connector and a
>       Red laser from the "Three Little Connectors... and a Fan" puzzle.
> 18. World C-4
>
>     Pictures of the developers: Before the "Stables" puzzle, jump on one of the left gargoyles and then on the wall. The pictures are on
>       the balcony, you can get up there using the "Casual" or the "Hardcore"
>       way.
> 19. World C-6
>
>     Diamond Sword from Minecraft: In the puzzle "Circumlocution", in the area where the Tetromino is you can find a gap in the wall hidden
>       by some trees. This sword can be used to slash some vines behind the
>       teleporter. It will reveal a QR code with a message in Croatian that
>       translates to "you are not here".
> 20. World C-7
>
>     Another Snowman: In the puzzle "Carrier Pigeons", it's in the area behind the altar. You can get there by stacking three hexahedron and
>       jumping on it from the nearest platform.
> 21. Nexus
>
>     QR code by a famous cracking group: Right of the elevator to the C world you can see a bunch of QR codes. Look at who signed the bottom
>       left one.
> 22. Tower
>
>     a) Hidden QR Code: From the floor 5, go out the window to the pigeons, then jump down on the left of to level 4's roof instead of
>       aiming for the star. From here jump again to the left and land on the
>       roof of floor 3's elevator. The QR code will be on the balcony on the
>       right of the elevator.
>
>     b) Serious Sam Game Poster: Take the same path than for the QR code, but instead of jumping down to the balcony at the end, jump to
>       the other side of it. From here you can jump on top of floor 2 puzzle.

Comment: You can sleep on the bed easter egg in B-2 to "Dream of Electric Sheep".